# @Binding付きの変数の初期化がわからない

Tags: swift, swiftui

SwiftUIにおいて`@Binding`付きの変数を`init`内で初期化しようとすると、
`'self' used before all stored properties are initialized`というエラーが発生します。

[このウェブページ](https://forums.swift.org/t/state-messing-with-initializer-flow/25276)によると、「`@State`はinitializerを通して得た値から初期化することはできない」とのことですが、これは`@Binding`でも同じことが言えるのでしょうか？

もしそうだとしたら、どのようにすればこのエラーを回避できますか？
Xcodeのバージョンは11.3.1で、Swiftのバージョンは5.1.3です。

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Icon {
    var imageName:String
    @Binding var selected:Bool

    init(_ image:String,_ state:Bool){
        self.imageName = image
        self.selected = state // 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized

    } //Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties
}
```

Comment: [以前のご質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/63300/13972)と同じ内容ですね。既に回答もついていますし、その回答が分かりにくいなどがあれば、そちらでコメントをつけるなどしてください。