# Swift Binding変数の初期化の仕方について

Tags: swift, swiftui

別の処理で必要な初期化がありstruct内にinit()を記載しましたが、Binding変数があるからか初期化でエラーが出ています。

”Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties”

@Binding変数は@State変数の中身を引き継いでいる為、そもそも初期化してしまったら、変数の中身の引き継ぎが出来ないのではないかとも考えてます。

質問
Binding変数を初期化する方法がありましたら、ご教授頂けますでしょうか。
コード一部抜粋は以下の通りです。

```
struct ConfirmView: View{

    var appSyncClient: AWSAppSyncClient?
    init() {
         let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
         appSyncClient = appDelegate.appSyncClient
     }

    @Binding var name:String
    @Binding var gender:Int
    @Binding var birthDate:Date
    @Binding var mail:String
    @Binding var password:String
    var seibetu = ["男","女"]
    var body: some View {
```

どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

### 追記

試したこと

初期化の部分に

```
init(name: Binding<String>,gender: Binding<Int>,birthdate: Binding<Date>,mail: Binding<String>,password: Binding<String>)
```

と記載してみましたが変わりませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

基本的には、[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/63305/13972)に説明したのと全く同じことになるのですが、

- **`@Binding`の付いたプロパティの初期化には、`_プロパティ名`と言うプロパティを`Binding<T>`型で初期化しないといけません。**

```
    init(name: Binding<String>, gender: Binding<Int>, birthdate: Binding<Date>, mail: Binding<String>, password: Binding<String>) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appSyncClient = appDelegate.appSyncClient

        self._name = name
        self._gender = gender
        self._birthDate = birthdate
        self._mail = mail
        self._password = password
    }
```

---

ただ、今回の場合、`appDelegate`なんて格納型プロパティを初期化する必要がなければ、`init()`を書く必要もなくなるので、Swiftがイニシャライザを自動生成してくれます。

例えばこんな感じ:

```
    var appSyncClient: AWSAppSyncClient? {
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).appSyncClient
    }
```

(この場合、`init()`の定義は削除する。)

Comment: 大変参考になりました。てっきりinit()が必要と思い込んでましたが、イニシャライザを自動生成することもできるのですね。有難う御座いました。